# App Script - getting the content of a spreedsheet cell and putting it into a text box in a website and clicking the button

Tags: google-apps-script

I am learning Google App Script and have a question. I am laerning it to do some automation in the future.

Let's assume I have a spreadsheet with cell A1. The content of this cell is "Test"

Let's assume there is a webpage like google. It has a text box and a button(submit button)

I would like to retrieve the content from the cell and put it into the text box. Then I want my script to "click" that button next to it.

Any keyword for me to look for it? Any hint? Am I looking for scrapping or automation? I also would really love to see an example, for example with Google search in order for me to apply it on the actual webpage I am aiming for.

The class name of textbox in Goole Search is class="A8SBwf" and for the button it is class="gNO89b".

Looking forward :))

Comment: The place to start is Google HTML Service https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty example.

In the script editor of your Spreadsheet Code.gs

```
function onOpen() {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Test");
  menu.addItem("Dialog","showDialog");
  menu.addToUi();
}

// required if you ever expand on a template
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
};

function showDialog() {
  try {
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('HTML_Demo').evaluate();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html,"Show Demo");
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}

function getCellA1() {
  try {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    return sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
  }
  catch(err) {
    return err.message;
  }
}
```

Then in the editor create a new HTML file HTML_Demo;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="A8SBwf" type="text">
    <input id="gNO89b" type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="buttonOnClick()">
    <script>
      function buttonOnClick() {
        try {
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( 
            function(response) {
              document.getElementById("A8SBwf").value = response;
            }
          ).getCellA1();
        }
        catch(err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

After that you're on your own.

Comment: Hello TheWizEd,

Thanks for your time and help! I really appreciate it.

This code helps me a lot to know how to proceed from here. I might have indeed more question in the future. AS for now I would like to ask how can I view this html code in my browser? I created a new html file in the editor but I dont know where it is saved and how I can see it on my browser. Any hint for me? :)

Comment: Edit: I think that my previous question doesnt make any sense on a second thought. What I actually wanted to know is that the script should also run the html code. Lets say this html is a search machine and I would like to see the result what my script does. From here I could then work myself step by step further.

Comment: You mention you are learning Google App script which means its either bound to a spreadsheet or its and add-on.  Everything I've shown is a bound script.  They can display an HTML dialog or sidebar and can interact with the spreadsheet.  If you're talking about a web based application outside of Google Spreadsheet then you can use the Spreadsheet API but that would require Authorications.  That becomes a lot more complicated.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you for this information. Seems like I didn't find the proper wording to explain myself. Much appreciating that you understood where I want to go. So the keyword I should look for should be "Spreadsheet API". I want to use GS because you don't need to install an app. The code you provided was still really helpful, however let's say I want GS to search in a search machine such as google search using the content of cell A1 from spreadsheet. Then it should give me the title of the first result from the search and insert it in cell A2. For this I need to dig my into Spreadsheet API?

Comment: By GS you mean Google App Script?  As I said that only runs in a bound script or add-on.  Not some other programming environment.

Comment: Yes, by GS i mean google app script. Would you recommend me to go with Python for web automation or scrapping? I am really confused but really thankful that you told me that before I went myself too deep into Google App Script. I just liked it coz it is kinda similar to JavaScript. I read about that person who worked for a lawyer agency and he wrote a script which did all his tasks. I thought I would be able to do that with ease. Laughing now at myself. Thought it would easy to just write a script and tell it to open a webpage, clicking a button, filling stuffs somewhere and save it etc. ^^

Comment: Only you really know what your objectives are.  And that may change and grow with time.  I showed how simple it is to have a custom dialog linked to a Google Spreadsheet, because you mentioned you wanted to get the value from cell A1 using a button and a text field.